# The margin-top property hits all the divs

Tags: html, css

I have three nested DIV elements.
When I insert margin-top into the inside div all others receive the effect.

I need the inside div to have a margin-top relative to the outside div and not the whole block.

I created an example in codepen. I have one div, two div and three div.

Notice that I put the margin-top in div three, but all divs receive the effect.

Does anyone know the reason?

```
<div class="um">

            <div class="dois">

                <div class="tres" style="margin-top: 50px;">

                        conteudo

                </div>

            </div>

</div>
```

[example codepen](https://codepen.io/renatosistemasvc/pen/aQwBqN?fbclid=IwAR0woC-5boxyBoPqz-z1rwexQMUkqJEx_6fNBdEeaBWihE_Mgn2THZF6qKM)

Answer (score 2):

use padding-top instead of margin-top.

```
<div class="um">
            <div class="dois">
                <div class="tres" style="padding-top: 50px;">
                        conteudo
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

default value tag div is `display:block`, add css on um class `display:flex`